# How to get data from website with interaction

Tags: r

I'd like to get data with R from following website: [Website MFarm](https://www.moneyfarm.com/it/portafogli/)

I'm wondering if there's a chance to get them from R or I must use something else (e.g. *Selenium*, or *Python*) ?

Note that:

- Needed data is the plot trend. This shouldn't be an issue, as it's only about getting a html attribute, and then to re-elaborate numbers within R.
- Data are shown in the page not immediately, but only some seconds after the page is loaded. So some `waitfor()` function shall be used
- There are 7 tabs. I need data from all of them. An interaction is therefore needed.
- There's a combo box and a text box with parameters I've to choose

Comment: You probably want to use the rvest R package for web scraping, there's plenty of tutorials online.

Comment: not sure I can navigate into tabs with rvest. I'm possibly needing RSelenium?